# hyper-v planned failover permanent

Tags: hyper-v

I have two Windows Server 2016 with Hyper-v role which run failover under workgroup. We do not have AD. 
I need to make a permanent planned failover, most docs I read mention planned failover as a temportary solution but we need to have the secondary server as primary due to better hardware?

How can do this? Thank you

Comment: anyone know about this?

Comment: Do  you want to remove the old hardware, or do you want to keep it in and prefer the new hardware?

Comment: I want to do a planned failover from server A where it's primary to serve B which is receiving the replication and acts as a secondary server. Then after planned failover server B will be primary. I am missing how to do the permanent planned failover so secondary will act as primary. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Customize your procedures to meet your hardware migration or business continuity requirements. Some people only cut over for a day to test their disaster recovery plan on a less-capable system. Your use case is different.

[Start a planned failover](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/set-up-hyper-v-replica#run-a-failover) from A to B and complete any other steps to move the system over. That is permanent, until it is failed over again.

Absent a failover cluster, there is not a concept of preference of which host. Just the running VM, and its replica.

Answer (score 0):

just posting here how I solve it.
Started from primary server ex. A a planned failover, powered down the primary VM and started planned failover from server B. Then from server B I did a reverse failover which is what I needed, changed the server B from replica to primary.